# OpenSuse: Cannot start Omnisharp because Mono version >=3.10.0 is required

Tags: opensuse, visual-studio-code

Im running Visual Studio Code on OpenSuse 13.2 and get "Cannot start Omnisharp because Mono version >=3.10.0 is required". I have reinstalled mono-complete and mono-devel.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSuse 13.2 repositories contains mono version 3.8.0. To install newer version, firstly uninstall current version of mono and then visit [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#opensuse-and-sles) page and click "**1-click Install mono-complete**" to install latest version of mono (currently version 4.0.2)